# linear transformation and matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I know that every linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ can be represented in a matrix form.
What about a transformation from a:

1. Infinite dimension to infinte dimension
2. finite to infinite dimension
3. infinite to finite dimension
   Can they represented by matrix form....?
   Before this another question is there a linear transformation from Infinite dimension to infinte dimension, finite to infinite dimension and vice versa..?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there're linear transformations finite-finite, infinite-infinite, infinite-finite, and finite-infinite dimensions. Just google for "linear operator".

As to matrix representation, finite-finite version is evident. In general case, as long as range or domain is infinite dimensioned, it's impossible to build a matrix. The key problem is that matrix form depends on basis in both domain and range of the application. In general linear space of infinite dimension we know the existence of a Hamel basis (cf. wiki) if we accept the axiom of choice. But this existence is implicit, there's no explicit construction of this basis, hence we can't write down the coefficient of the matrix. If we work with Hilbert basis, then it's simplified a little.

Sometimes in some simple cases we can say that a certain linear operator $T$ can be viewed as a matrix (i.e. we know basis in both range ($r_j$) and domain ($d_i$), and we can develop $Td_i$ in the basis $r_j$), but again, in general case mathematicians prefer just to think about linear operator and not its matrix form.